# Bind jquery mouseover dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, mouseover

Hi I need some help with jquery; I've this HTML

```
<div id="1">1</div>
<div id="2">2</div>
<div id="3">3</div>
<label id="schedId"></label>
```

and I want to show in the label the div id where mouse is over.
I tried with this:

```
for(var i = 1; i < 4; i++)
{
    $('#' + i.toString()).bind('mouseover', function () { 
        $("#schedId").text(i.toString());
    });
    $('#' + i.toString()).bind('mouseout', function () { 
        $("#schedId").text("");
    });
}
```

but I read always '4' in the label. Could you help me please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake

Comment: Id can not start with ineteger

Answer (score 0):

Add a class of `element` to each `div`,

And you can do something like this:

```
$(".element").hover(
    function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $("#schedId").text(id);
    }, function () {
        // mouseout code here 
    }
);
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4L5Uj/)**